# Set Date Picker time format

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have this example of Date Picker. Can you tell me how I can set the date format of the calendar?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class PickerDemo extends Application {
    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        final DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker(LocalDate.now());
        datePicker.setOnAction(event -> {
            LocalDate date = datePicker.getValue();
            System.out.println("Selected date: " + date);
        });

        stage.setScene(
            new Scene(datePicker)
        );
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Here : http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/ find javadoc for DatePicker, and look at converter property description. Also, please, remove label "javafx-2".

Comment: Any example how I can use this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
datePicker.setConverter(new StringConverter<LocalDate>()
{
    private DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @Override
    public String toString(LocalDate localDate)
    {
        if(localDate==null)
            return "";
        return dateTimeFormatter.format(localDate);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate fromString(String dateString)
    {
        if(dateString==null || dateString.trim().isEmpty())
        {
            return null;
        }
        return LocalDate.parse(dateString,dateTimeFormatter);
    }
});
```